# How do I submit an html form after modifying the format of the inputs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a simple html form and am trying to post the inputs in json format to an endpoint.

How do I get the form to submit with jsonInputs?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('[contact-form]').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    jsonInputs = $(this).serializeArray().reduce(function(a, x) {
      a[x.name] = x.value;
      return a;
    }, {});

    console.log(jsonInputs);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" name="emailform" action="/rest/contact" contact-form>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputName">Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Name" maxlength="50">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputMessage">Message</label>
    <textarea type="text" name="message" class="form-control" id="inputMessage" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: `this.submit()` will ignore your jquery event handler

Comment: Use Ajax request for that

Comment: Never call ANYTHING submit `name="submit" `

Comment: To send: `$('[name=emailform]').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();$.post(this.action,$(this).serialize(),function(data) { console.log("done",data) });});`

Comment: `$('[contact-form]').submit();` or `this.submit();`

Comment: @bassxzero do I pass `jsonInputs` to `this.submit()`? and @Justinas can you be a little more specific? I'm sorry, I'm sure these explanations should be enough but I've never made an ajax request or written javascript before so I really need to be spoonfed.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this could help you

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            $('[contact-form]').on('submit', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var x = document.getElementById('contact-form');
                var json = {
                    "name" : x.elements[0],
                    "email": x.elements[1],
                    "message": x.elements[2]
                }
                xhttp.open("POST", "/rest/contact", true);
                xhttp.send();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id='contact-form' method="post" name="emailform" action="/rest/contact" contact-form>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="inputName">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Name" maxlength="50">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputMessage">Message</label>
            <textarea type="text" name="message" class="form-control" id="inputMessage" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't look like this actually submits the form with the json. I need to submit `jsonInputs` to the original endpoint.

Comment: You can do that by creating your own json with the received data.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm sure what you are saying is very basic but I have never written javascript before and am not certain what you mean. Within `$('[contact-form]').on('submit', function (e) {...` I have defined `jsonInputs`. I would like that to be posted to the endpoint, aka, I would like the form to do what it would ussually do on submit but with jsonInputs as the data. So instead of `e.preventDefault();
` I would like to do the default behavior but with `jsonInputs` as the data submitted.